# Узнать версию компилятора по итоговой программе

Tags: visual-studio

У меня есть исполняемый файл. Достоверно известно, что он скомпилирован в чём-то из пакета Visual Studio. Можно ли узнать версию компилятора и студии, с помощью которых этот файл был создан?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае это сделать крайне сложно. Но обычно это достаточно легко. Для этого понадобится программа Dependency Walker - раньше она шла с студией, а сейчас можно просто поискать в интернете (или любая другая, которая показывает, какие dll требуются программе). В списке dll ищем что то похожее на `VC*XXX.DLL`, где * - какие то символы, ХХХ - цифры. По цифрам легко угадать, к примеру VCRUNTIME140.DLL - это компилятор от 2015 студии (версия компилятора 14.0). Другие соостветствия можно посмотреть хоть в [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_and_64-bit_versions).

2017 студия умеет использовать компилятор от 2015 студии. Поэтому, если версию компилятора легко угадать, то версию студии часто просто не возможно (никто не мешает писать код в блокноте или visual studio code).

Также существуют разные программы, которые ищут "отпечатки компилятора" (fingerprint). Например, PEiD. Но большинство таких программ обычно являются "инструментами взломщика".